# how to modify multiple columns at once?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider this simple example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dt_one': ['2015-01-01', '2016-02-02'],
              'dt_two': ['2015-01-01', '2016-02-02'],
              'other_col': [1, 2]})

df    
Out[30]: 
       dt_one      dt_two  other_col
0  2015-01-01  2015-01-01          1
1  2016-02-02  2016-02-02          2
```

I want to apply `pd.to_datetime` to all the columns that contain `dt_`

I can easily do so with `filter`

```
df.filter(regex = 'dt_').apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))
Out[33]: 
      dt_one     dt_two
0 2015-01-01 2015-01-01
1 2016-02-02 2016-02-02
```

However, how can these values be assigned in the original dataframe?
Doing:

```
df.filter(regex = 'dt_') = df.filter(regex = 'dt_').apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))
  File "<ipython-input-34-412d88939494>", line 1
    df.filter(regex = 'dt_') = df.filter(regex = 'dt_').apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

does not work

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need assign to filtered columns:

```
cols =  df.filter(regex = 'dt_').columns         
df[cols] = df[cols].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))
print (df)
      dt_one     dt_two  other_col
0 2015-01-01 2015-01-01          1
1 2016-02-02 2016-02-02          2
```

Or assign to columns selected by `mask`:

```
m =  df.columns.str.contains('dt_')    
df.loc[:,m] = df.loc[:,m].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))
print (df)
      dt_one     dt_two  other_col
0 2015-01-01 2015-01-01          1
1 2016-02-02 2016-02-02          2
```

Comment: I tried to apply the same approach to my dataframe but it didn't seems to be working. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59699910/how-to-apply-the-same-function-with-different-input-arguments-to-create-new-colu

Answer (score 4):

The method din't work because `df.filter(regex='dt_')` is a modified copy. For assigning data for multiple columns you need to select the columns from the actual dataframe with index based selection or assign it inplace using `assign`.

So after filtering get the columns and do a boolean indexing before assigning it i.e

```
df[df.filter(regex = 'dt_').columns] = df.filter(regex = 'dt_').apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))
```

```
     dt_one     dt_two  other_col
0 2015-01-01 2015-01-01          1
1 2016-02-02 2016-02-02          2
```

Comment: thanks bharath very clear, however I think jezrael was first and submitted the same answer. thanks again!

Comment: I was in such a hurry to answer. I knew jez will come for this. Thats why I posted code first, though couldn't beat him.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "unpacking" with `assign`:

```
df_out = df.assign(**df.filter(regex = 'dt_').apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x)))

      dt_one     dt_two  other_col
0 2015-01-01 2015-01-01          1
1 2016-02-02 2016-02-02          2
```

And info:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2 entries, 0 to 1
Data columns (total 3 columns):
dt_one       2 non-null datetime64[ns]
dt_two       2 non-null datetime64[ns]
other_col    2 non-null int64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), int64(1)
memory usage: 128.0 bytes
```

Comment: I think upacking is native to python as a language.  This method creates a new dataframe where as the others answers here modify the original dataframe.  You could use this method for better error tracking and rolling back. to previous dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the value like this .

```
df['dt_one'],df['dt_two']=df.filter(regex = 'dt_').apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x)).values


df.dtypes
Out[215]: 
dt_one       datetime64[ns]
dt_two       datetime64[ns]
other_col             int64
dtype: object
```