# How to apply the same function with different input arguments to create new columns in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe

So i've this sample dataframe:

```
      x_mean    x_min    x_max     y_mean     y_min     y_max
 1      85.6        3      264       75.7         3       240
 2     105.5        6      243       76.4         3       191
 3      95.8       19      287       48.4         8       134
 4      85.5       50      166       64.8        32       103
 5      55.9       24      117       46.7        19        77 


x_range = [list(range(0,50)),list(range(51,100)),list(range(101,250)),list(range(251,350)),list(range(351,430)),list(range(431,1000))]
y_range = [list(range(0,30)),list(range(31,60)),list(range(61,90)),list(range(91,120)),list(range(121,250)),list(range(251,2000))]


#here x = Any column with mean value (eg. x_mean or y_mean)
# y = x_range / y_range 

def min_max_range(x,y):
for a in y:
    if int(x) in a:
        min_val = min(a)
        max_val = max(a)+1
        return max_val - min_val

def min_range(x,y):
for a in y:
    if int(x) in a:
        min_val = min(a)
        return min_val
```

Now i want to apply these function `min_max_range()` and `min_range()` to column `x_mean, y_mean` to get new columns.

Like the function `min_max_val` is using column `x_mean` & the range `x_range` as the input to create column `x_min_max_val` , similarly column `y_mean` & the range `y_range` are used for the column `y_min_max_val` :

I can create each column one by one, by using these one liners, but i want to apply this to both column `x_mean & y_mean` columns in one go with a one liner.

```
df['x_min_max_val'] = df['x_mean'].apply(lambda x: min_max_range(x,x_range))
df['y_min_max_val'] = df['y_mean'].apply(lambda x: min_max_range(x,y_range))
```

The resultant dataframe should look like this:

```
      x_mean    x_min    x_max     y_mean     y_min     y_max    x_min_max_val   y_min_max_val        x_min_val   y_min_val
1      85.6        3      264       75.7         3       240                49              29               51          61
2     105.5        6      243       76.4         3       191               149              29              101          91
3      95.8       19      287       48.4         8       134                49              29               51          91
4      85.5       50      166       64.8        32       103                49              29               51          61
5      55.9       24      117       46.7        19        77                49              29               51          31
```

I want to create these columns in one go, instead of creating one column ata time. How can i do this? Any suggestions? or something like this could work?

```
df.filter(regex='mean').apply(lambda x: min_max_range(x,x+'_range'))
```

Comment: are these the functions you are using or are they just for example?

Comment: I'm using them. @Datanovice

Comment: @astroluv it is hard to understand what you are after. so you want your function min_max_range to take input x_mean and x_range and spit out the columns specified?

Comment: currently, your `min_max_range` would return None as no values in `y_mean` are in `x_mean` ?  also passing in columns results in an error

Comment: Also, how do you currently do it and how are you hoping to make it 'in one go' ?

Comment: If you give any random number and "x_range" as an input to the function "min_max_range", it gives a certain output. Now i'm trying to apply this function to column, which is not working.

Comment: Because i've a different "range" for each column, like "x_range" for "x_mean",   "y_range" for "y_mean" column. So that's why i want to achieve this in one go, instead of repeating it again n again.

Comment: df['x_mean'].apply(lambda x: min_max_range(x,x_range))  , this works to create a new column.  But i want to do this for all the column in one go. Did you get what i'm trying to say? @Datanovice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the concept that you need to follow to make this happen. First you need to have your ranges stored in a dictionary to enable access to them through names.

```
range_dict = {}
range_dict['x_range'] = x_range
range_dict['y_range'] = y_range
```

Also, you need to have the columns that you need to do the calculation for in a list (or you can use regex to get those if they have a specific pattern)

```
mean_cols_list = ['x_mean', 'y_mean']
```

Now, to apply your function over all columns, you need to define a function like this

```
def min_max_calculator(df, range_dictionary, mean_columns_list):
    for i in range(len(mean_cols_list)):
        # this returns 'x_mean'
        current_column = mean_cols_list[i]
        # this returns 'x_min_max_value'
        output_col_name = current_column.replace('mean','min_max_value')
        # this returns 'x_range'
        range_name = current_column.replace('mean','range')
        # this returns the list of ranges for x_range
        range_list = range_dict[range_name]
        # This add the calculated column to the dataframe
        df[output_col_name] = df[current_column].apply(lambda x: min_max_range(x,range_list))
    return(df)

df_output = min_max_calculator(df, range_dict, mean_cols_list)
```

Comment: How can i add an another column that will use the other columns to get a new column.    x_new =  df.x_min_max_val / ( df.x_max - df.x_min ) * (df.x_mean - df.x_min) + df.x_min_max_val